# Is it possible to use typescript in nuxt serverMiddleware?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

I just started learning nuxtjs. In my setup, I selected to use typescript. Everything works fine until I wanted to integrate express in the serverMiddleware. Using require statement to require express works fine. But when I change it to use import statement to enable proper type-checking, it throws an error saying

> SyntaxError
>
> > Cannot use import statement outside a module

In nuxt.config.js default export I have the following line:

```
export default {
serverMiddleware: ['~/api/app']
}
```

In the api/app.ts file I have the following code:

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(
        'message'
    );
})

module.exports = {
    path: '/api',
    handler: app
};
```

This throws the error:

> SyntaxError
>
> > Cannot use import statement outside a module

If I change the import statement to:
`const express = require('express')`, everything works fine.

**Is there anyway to configure nuxtjs serverMiddleware to use typescript explicitly?**

Comment: Yes. Have a [look at the documentation for this portion](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/runtime.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just `import { ServerMiddleware } from '@nuxt/types'`